# Save Log at Realtime without freeze appplication on multithreaded ambient

Tags: delphi

How's the properly way for save logs at .txt on multithreaded application where every log should be saved at real-time?

Actually i use the code:

```
constructor TLog.Create(const AMsg: String; const Exibe: Boolean);
begin
  FMsg := AMsg;
  FExibe := Exibe;
  inherited Create;
end;

procedure TLog.DoSynchronize;
var
  NameF: String;
  Arq: TextFile;
begin
  try
    NameF := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'Logs\FILE_' + FormatDateTime('dd_mm_yyyy', Now) + '.txt';
    AssignFile(Arq, NameF);

    if FileExists(NameF) then
      Append(Arq)
    else
      ReWrite(Arq);
    try
      Write(Arq, FMsg);
    finally
      CloseFile(Arq);
    end;
  except
  end;

  if Form1.CheckBox1.Checked then Exit;

  if FExibe then Form1.Memo2.Lines.Add(FMsg);
end;

class procedure TLog.AddMsg(const AMsg: String; const Exibe: Boolean);
begin
  with Create(AMsg, Exibe) do
    try
      Synchronize;
    finally
      Free;
    end;
end;
```

but since i call it every time application starts freeze.
What's the best method of generate logs without this "freeze"?

Comment: You need to use queues which are processed in different threads.

Comment: So change Synchronize to Queue on AddMsg?

Comment: No. You need to make a completely different infrastructure. You need to define a `TLogMessage = class(TObject)` and have a `TObjectQueue<TLogMessage>` and a `QueueLock: TCriticalSection` and a `QueueEvent: TEvent`. Then, in your `Log` function, which can be called from any thread, you enter the critical section and append your new log item and set the event to signalled. You also need to create a `TThread` which waits on this event and when signalled enters the critical section, swaps the queue pointer with a different one, and then leaves the critical section.

Comment: (cont.) Then, outside of the critical section, the log handler thread can do anything it wants to do, and it doesn't even need to do it particularly fast.

Comment: Do not use synchronize! It makes the file I/O done in the main thread, blocking it. Put the log code in his own thread. Use a queue to add messages, the log thread will read the queue and write to disk. Pay attention to not overflow the queue/memory if file I/O is slower than the speed at which the queue is filled. Don't forget to use/write a thread safe queue.

Comment: I've created a thread who run every 500 seconds using while true and SleepEx, this thread loop a TStringList with the logs for save and delete on for loop, the problem is. when use tCriticalSection on add and on for/delete it make program run slower.

Comment: (1) Use a queue, not a list. (2) Don't use `Sleep(Ex)`, use `WaitForSingleObject` or `WaitForMultipleObjects` and wait for the event which is set to signalled by the central log function which enqueues new log messages. (3) Within the critical section, you must be extremely quick. Just swap the incoming queue with a new, empty queue. Just swapping two pointers is really fast. (4) You also need a termination event, set in the thread's dtor, so you can exit your app.

Comment: I could write a simple example for you, but I don't think that would be appropriate given the Stack Overflow guidelines.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, if you write it as solution should help me so much, then i test it here.
Basically i use TLod.AddMsg on some functions of TcpServer, my tests here didn't solved my issue. if you can help with a demo will help so much. i'm testing it flooding tcpserver with connection/disconnection and these informations is saved on .txt

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand can u create a simple example?